# Swift 3 Charts Bar Graph Nil

Tags: swift

I am getting the following error:

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

My code is as follows and the function is called in my viewDidLoad:

```
 func setChart() {

        let months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
        let unitsSold = [20.0, 4.0, 6.0, 3.0, 12.0, 16.0, 4.0, 18.0, 2.0, 4.0, 5.0, 4.0]


        var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []


        for i in 0..<months.count {

            let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(months[i])!, y: Double(unitsSold[i]))

            dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
        }

        let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Visitor count")

        let chartData = BarChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)

        barChartView.data = chartData

    }
```

The code seems to break at the `let dataEntry` line.

Comment: You months array constains names of months and you are trying to convert into Double e.g x: Double("Jan")!  , this will always crash, what are you trying to do here?

Comment: Trying to make a simple bar graph with months as the x axis and units sold as the y axis.

Comment: You are using a library to make graphs?

Comment: Yes a library called Graphs located here:  https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

Comment: Can you show the code for the complete class in which you are writing the above code?

Comment: @user1000 thats the whole function and its just in a regular viewcontroller class and in the viewDidLoad I call the function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152806/discussion-between-user1000-and-martheli).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You months array constains names of months and you are trying to convert into Double e.g x: Double("Jan")! , this will always crash,

so first replace

`Double(months[i])!` with `Double(i)`

and then to get the axis labels

After discussion with OP, we found the following solution to add labels to x-axis

```
yourchartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values:months) 
yourchartview.xAxis.granularity = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `Double(months[i])` will return `nil` when it's passed a string, which is what the values in the `months` array are, and since you're force-unwrapping it (with '!'), it bombs.

Comment: Do you know how to pass the string months to display in the graph?